# DPM 2010 Confusion

Tags: scdpm

Ok, I'm very confused when it comes to DPM 2010.  I have numerous physical and virtual machines (running Hyper-V), connected to a SAN via iSCSI and they are clustered.  With DPM 2010, I want to be able to restore individual files from within my virtual machines and I also want the option to recover the entire Virtual machine in a DR situation.  I also have Exchange 2010 to backup.  I am backing up to disk for short term backup and tape for long term.

How can I do this?  I have also found out that DPM 2010 doesn't backup the system states to tape....why is this?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to read the documentation on this.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff634207.aspx and dpm does do system state or bare metal recover...

Comment: I read that DPM does not support system state backups to tape and hence why none of mine have worked.  I checked the above link and I have double clicked my VHD and nothing, when I read further, I found that VHDs sitting on ISCSI storage, are not supported.....

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff399536.aspx

Comment: vhd sitting on a iscsi lun presented to the host should work fine, the doc seeminly is talking about if you use a iscsi lun as a passthru to a guest. This statement " iSCSI to present volumes to the VIRTUAL MACINE" is confusing this sounds like passthru disks. On a virtual machine system state would not make sense since you backup the vhd which also includes system state.

Comment: When I attempt a test restore, I see Backup using Child Partition snapshot\server name and the drive letter assigned to that virtual machine.  For some reason the replica for the child partition bit isn't working but I will look at this soon.  When I double click the drive letter and see a folder with the name of the virtual server and then a VHD for both the C and D drives.  It won't let me dig deeper but maybe I'm looking at this wrong....sorry I'm new to this which i'm sure you can tell.